# Error when rendering rails form_tag partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial

The situation is the following:
I have one `form_tag` that will be rendered inside two views, but with different urls in each view. Ex:

```
<%= form_tag form_url, method: 'GET' do %>
     <%= ... %>
     <%= ... %>
     <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

I wanna call that like this:

On view A:

```
<%= render "form_partial_name", locals: { form_url: url_A } %>
```

On view B:

```
<%= render "form_partial_name", locals: { form_url: url_B } %>
```

But it doesn`t work. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `render partial:` instead of `render`

```
<%= render partial: "form_partial_name", locals: { form_url: url_A } %>
<%= render partial: "form_partial_name", locals: { form_url: url_B } %>
```

Because `render` don't support locals.

[Read](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) more.

There is also another way. You can also use `yield` and `provide`:

```
<%= form_tag yield(:form_url), method: 'GET' do %>
     <%= ... %>
     <%= ... %>
     <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

And 2 different views:

```
<% provide(:form_url, url_A) %>
<%= render "form_partial_name" %>
```

```
<% provide(:form_url, url_B) %>
<%= render "form_partial_name" %>
```

Comment: I added another way. You can try it too.

Comment: Awesome way, I think it pretty more clean. tks.